# Is it possible to publish and use a React component library without building/compiling/bundling the library code?

Tags: reactjs, package, jsx

So i've read a couple of articles on stack overflow that are *almost* the same but not exactly.
I would like to publish my component library (which only i will use) without building, compiling or bundling any of the code.

Basically what i'm look for is that the package folder inside the node_modules folder consists of raw react components with uncompiled JSX and import and use that inside of my react application.

I feel like this should be possible but i keep getting the following error when importing a component from this library:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. 
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I've tried adding these plugins as configuration using a .babelrc AND a babel.config file to both the application root AND the package root. which did absolutely nothing in both cases.

Is it even possible, and if yes, how?

Thanks in advance